# slickgrid conditional formatting and selection coloring priority

Tags: javascript, css, html, slickgrid

I have conditional format to one of my columns in slick grid and it works fine. I also have a cell section formatting that works as well. The cell formatting seems to take priority over selection formatting, so if I click on the cell it partially works background gets applied but foreground does not. Is there a way to get the priority switched i.e on selection use that over the default cell format?

```
function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
            if (value === 'A') {
                return "<span style='color:#FF0000'>" + value + "</span>";
            }

            if (value === 'B') {
                return "<span style='color:#00FF00'>" + value + "</span>";
            }

};

.slick-cell.selected {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional format foreground takes priority over the default selection foreground. Setting the selection foreground style to be `!important` solves the issue.

```
.slick-cell.selected > span {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Would you please mind adding some textual explanation to your answer? It might help a lot for future readers.